# Php что быстрее != или strlen

Tags: php, производительность

Такой вопросик. Делаю проверку входящих GET данных . Для запуска валидации требуется узнать есть ли GET переменные. Есть у меня два варианта, хотелось бы услышать мнение знающих людей какой из них лучше применять:

```
1) strlen($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) != 0

2) $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] != ''
```

Comment: А у Вас производительность просела на этом месте, да ?  
И кстати, разве может  

    $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']  
быть пустым ? Там как минимум будет хотя бы  

    /

Comment: Производительность не просела. Перебираю разные варианты. И благодарю, действительно как минимум слеш присутствует.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Не изобретайте велосипед, используйте функцию [filter_input()](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.filter-input.php). Там полно встроенных фильтров проверки, например

```
$test_input_var = filter_input(INPUT_GET, "var", FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);
```

таким образом мы проверим, является ли переданный аргумент целым числом или нет. В случае успеха, переменная `$test_input_var` будет содержать либо значение аргумента, либо `FALSE` в случае провала, либо `NULL` если переменная не была инициализирована.

Далее, при помощи оператора ветвления if, можно писать логику, например

```
define(MIN_AGE, 18);

if( $test_input_var === MIN_AGE )
{
    //выполняем код в случае успеха
} else {
    //код, который будет при FALSE и NULL.        
}
```

Comment: Немного не то что требовалось, но мысль интересная. спасибо.

Answer (score 3):

есть ли GET переменные

```
isset($_GET['var'])
!empty($_GET['var'])
```

Comment: Использовал такой вариант. Но сильно много if'ов получается.

Comment: а strlen меньше ифов? Неясно.

Comment: Если брать $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], то часть условий будет заменено explode.